# Автоматическая "нарезка" SMS

Tags: java, android

В приложении надо отсылать `SMS` которое формируется из разных `String`, разной длинны. Надо контролировать чтобы в 1 `SMS` небыло более 160 символов (т.к. `SMS` не отсылается в данном случае). Сейчас я это делаю так, как показано в коде ниже, но есть проблема, иногда ввожу такие данные, что когда приложение должно отправить 3 `SMS` - Первая `SMS`-ка не отправляется(превышен лимит символов).

Формат `SMS`-ок такой: `$xz%тело сообщения%`, где $-означает начало сообщения, X-Количество `SMS`, Z-порядковый номер `SMS`, %-разделительный знак

```
String message = UserSMS+SystemSMS+IO1SMS+OtherTextSMS;
    int UserLength = UserSMS.length();
    int SystemLength = SystemSMS.length();
    int IOLength = IO1SMS.length();
    int OtherTextLength = OtherTextSMS.length();
    Log.d(TAG, "UserSMS Length = "+UserLength);
    Log.d(TAG, "System SMS Length = "+SystemLength);
    Log.d(TAG, "IO Length = "+IOLength);
    Log.d(TAG, "OtherText Length = "+OtherTextLength);
    int length = message.length();
    if (length < 155) {
        sendSmsMessage(phone_number, "$11" + message+"%");
    }
    else if (length < 315){
        sendSmsMessage(phone_number, "$21"+UserSMS+SystemSMS+OtherTextSMS+"%");

        sendSmsMessage(phone_number, "$22"+ReactionTime + AlarmCall +RestoreCall+AlarmSMS+RestoreSMS+InputInverce+i5pswrd_sms+"%");
    }
    else if (length < 475){
        sendSmsMessage(phone_number, "$31"+ UserSMS+SystemSMS+ReactionTime + AlarmCall +RestoreCall+AlarmSMS+RestoreSMS+InputInverce+i5pswrd_sms+"%");
        sendSmsMessage(phone_number, "$32"+ z1_alarm_sms+z2_alarm_sms+z3_alarm_sms+z4_alarm_sms+arm_sms+
                z1_restore_sms+z2_restore_sms+z3_restore_sms+z4_restore_sms+"%");
        sendSmsMessage(phone_number, "$33"+ disarm_sms+ OtherTextSMS+"%");
    }
    else {
        sendSmsMessage(phone_number, "$41" +UserSMS+calltimessms+workmodesms+power_analise_sms+lifepulsesms+moneynubsms+ReactionTime+AlarmCall+RestoreCall+"%");
        sendSmsMessage(phone_number, "$42" +AlarmSMS+RestoreSMS+ok1sms+ok2sms+InputInverce+EntryExit+i5pswrd_sms+z1_alarm_sms+z2_alarm_sms+z3_alarm_sms+z4_alarm_sms+arm_sms+"%");
        sendSmsMessage(phone_number, "$43" +z1_restore_sms+z2_restore_sms+z3_restore_sms+z4_restore_sms+disarm_sms+"%");
        sendSmsMessage(phone_number, "$44" +OtherTextSMS+"%");
    }
```

Вот перечень всех `String`

```
String Numbers = userp2smss+userp3smss+userp4smss;
        if (Numbers.isEmpty()) {
            UserSMS = Notif1+Notif2+Notif3+Notif4;
        }
        else UserSMS = Numbers+Notif1+Notif2+Notif3+Notif4;

SystemSMS = calltimessms + workmodesms + power_analise_sms + lifepulsesms + moneynubsms + ok1sms + ok2sms + EntryExit;

IO1SMS = ReactionTime + AlarmCall +RestoreCall+AlarmSMS+RestoreSMS+InputInverce+i5pswrd_sms+z1_alarm_sms+z2_alarm_sms+z3_alarm_sms+z4_alarm_sms+arm_sms+
                z1_restore_sms+z2_restore_sms+z3_restore_sms+z4_restore_sms+disarm_sms;

OtherTextSMS = pulse_sms+money_sms+ac_fail_sms+ac_restore_sms+dc_fail_sms+dc_restore_sms+ac_fail_2_sms+acc_fail_sms;
```

Comment: А какая связь между длиной `UserSMS+SystemSMS+IO1SMS+OtherTextSMS` и `UserSMS+SystemSMS+ReactionTime + AlarmCall +RestoreCall+AlarmSMS+RestoreSMS+InputInverce+i5pswrd_sms`?

Comment: @zRrr всё, исправил